# Turning a USB Flash Drive into Password Key with Free Software

Tags: linux, passwords, usb-flash-drive

I read an [article](http://lifehacker.com/5879117/how-to-build-a-nearly-hack+proof-password-system-with-lastpass-and-a-thumb-drive?tag=lastpass) on Lifehacker the other day which showed you how to turn a USB flash drive into a "master password key" using LastPass (and some proprietary program LastPass licenses). Obviously, this is both a super neat and incredibly awesome idea that I'd like to do. Unfortunately, I'm a cheap person and don't want to pay for the LastPass subscription and software. I'm curious if there is any free software available that would do the same thing.

If it makes any difference, I primarily use Linux for day-to-day use, so this software would have to work with Linux.

Also, if my question is not very clear, I encourage you to read the Lifehacker article. Actually, read it anyway. It's rather neat.

**ANSWER:**

So I decided to simply use KeePassX (a fork of KeePass which works on Linux) and store the password DB on a flash drive. I encrypted the flash drive so Joe Schmoe won't be able to get access to all of my passwords. Not EXACTLY what I had in mind, but meh, not a huge deal.

Comment: Well, you could always encrypt your password database and use a random file as the encryption key. Then put the file on your USB drive.

Comment: I've been thinking about doing that, actually. I've done a bit of research on it. I'll edit the OP when I found a solid answer.

Comment: I actually use [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) for password storage, and I keep it with me on a USB key secured to my keys. So, in a way, the USB key becomes the password storage, not just the key to it.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg That's what I decided upon doing, in the end. It works well for what I want to do. Plus, I can encrypt my flash drive so no one can get in.

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it as an answer, not edit it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this would work with Linux so feel free to dispose of if this doesn't meet your requirements.  I use a product called [Password Agent](http://www.moonsoftware.com/pwagent.asp) which allows a "take with you" usb key version and also provides a lite version for free.

Comment: I think that it's Windows only. Oh well. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to simply use KeePassX (a fork of KeePass which works on Linux) and store the password DB on a flash drive. I encrypted the flash drive so Joe Schmoe won't be able to get access to all of my passwords. Not EXACTLY what I had in mind, but meh, not a huge deal.